# "Configuration System Failed to Initialize" when .Net Executable moved to Program Files (x86) folder

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a baffling one: A call to GetSetting from within my VB.Net (v4.5.2) Windows Forms app results in a "Configuration System Failed to Initialize" error--but only when the .exe and the .exe.config are moved to their deployment folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\MySubfolder. As soon as I drag the same two files out to the desktop (or anywhere else) it runs without error. (And for that matter, the development copy runs as well).

What could be causing this, and what steps can I take to troubleshoot?

Comment: It depends on what `GetSettings` does - if it tries to read/load/save from a file in `Program Files` it will fail due to persmissions

Comment: A random guess is that you did this before, but with different settings.  So it keels over on an old user.config file.  Project > Properties > Application tab > Assembly Information button > increment the assembly version number.

Comment: Typo in original, the code is to the built-in "GetSetting" (not GetSettings"). E.g.  GetSetting("MyProduct", "Settings", "SerialNum", "")

Comment: Interestingly, the code does run if you change the assembly version (!). Any idea why? (GetSetting/SaveSetting store to the registry, not Program Files (x86)